# Deriving the joint MGF for $U = XY + (1-X)Z$, $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p=1/3), Y \sim \text{Exp}(\theta = 2), Z \sim \text{Poi}(\lambda = 3)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

The question is to find the MGF of $U = XY + (1-X)Z$, where:

$X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli} (p = \frac{1}{3})$

$Y \sim \operatorname{EXP} (\theta = 2)$ (Note that the notation is $\theta = \operatorname{E} (Y)$ for this distribution)

$Z \sim \operatorname{POI} (\lambda = 3)$

My (intuitive...?) thought process is that:

$$\operatorname{P} (X = x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}, & x = 1 \\
\frac{2}{3}, & x = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

So

$$ U = XY + (1 - X)Z = \begin{cases}
Y & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{3} \\
Z & \text{with probability } \frac{2}{3} \\
\end{cases}$$

Then:

$$\operatorname{M}_U(t) = \operatorname{E} (e^{tU}) = \operatorname{E} (e^{t(XY + (1 - X)Z}) =  \operatorname{P} (e^{tU} = e^{tY}) \operatorname{E}(e^{tY}) + \operatorname{P} (e^{tU} = e^{tZ}) \operatorname{E}(e^{tZ})$$

I don't really know how to explain this simplification: it's kind of intuitive. Can someone please explain if it is correct, and if so, why?

This is pretty much my question. Here's the rest of the derivation:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{M}_U(t) & = \cdots = \operatorname{P} (e^{tU} = e^{tY}) \operatorname{E}(e^{tY}) + \operatorname{P} (e^{tU} = e^{tZ}) \operatorname{E}(e^{tZ}) \\
& = \operatorname{P} (X = 1) \operatorname{E}(e^{tY}) + \operatorname{P} (X = 0) \operatorname{E}(e^{tZ}) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \operatorname{E}(e^{tY}) + \frac{2}{3} \operatorname{E}(e^{tZ}) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \operatorname{M}_Y(t) + \frac{2}{3} \operatorname{M}_Z(t) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{1 - 2t} + \frac{2}{3} e^{3(e^t-1)} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Also: X, Y, Z are independent!

Comment: It is enough if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ and $Z$ are independent. You do not need that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):$$\mathsf Ee^{tU}=\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=1]\mathsf P(X=1)+\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=0]\mathsf P(X=0)=$$$$\frac13\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=1]+\frac23\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=0]=\frac13\mathsf E[e^{tY}\mid X=1]+\frac23\mathsf E[e^{tZ}\mid X=0]$$

This because $\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=1]=\mathsf E[e^{tY}\mid X=1]$ and $\mathsf E[e^{tU}\mid X=0]=\mathsf E[e^{tZ}\mid X=0]$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\mathsf E[e^{tY}\mid X=1]=\mathsf Ee^{tY}$.

If $X$ and $Z$ are independent then $\mathsf E[e^{tZ}\mid X=0]=\mathsf Ee^{tZ}$.

So under these conditions (they are not mentioned in your question) you end up with:$$M_U(t)=\mathsf Ee^{tU}=\frac13\mathsf Ee^{tY}+\frac23\mathsf Ee^{tZ}=\frac13M_Y(t)+\frac23M_Z(t)$$

Comment: Did you meant to write $\operatorname{E} (e^{tU} \vert X = 1) = \operatorname{E} (e^{tY})$ instead of $\operatorname{E} (e^{tY} \vert X = 1) = \operatorname{E} (e^{tY})$? Likewise for $Z$.

Comment: I have added a step to make things more clear. If $U=XY+(1-X)Z$ then $(U\mid X=1)=Y$. That is: the distribution of $U$ under condition $X=1$ is the same as the distribution of $Y$.